# What's the proper way to migrate from Date to LocalDate in Java 8?

Tags: java, date, java-time

I'm currently working on a legacy codebase where `Date` was used everywhere, and continues to be used because `Date`s are everywhere (entities contain `Date`s, services expect `Date`s, etc.). For some cases where the time portion shouldn't be used, we remove it from the `Date` object by using basically the following standard snippet in a utility method.

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
return cal.getTime();
```

I'd like to start using `LocalDate` for these cases. From what I could find, the standard recommended way of converting is (at least in Java 8):

```
date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

What I'm a bit uneasy about is the `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` part. Could I get different `LocalDate`s depending on which system the code is executed? I guess I could extract the year, month and day from the `Date` and construct a new `LocalDate` by explicitly passing the year, month and day, but I would like to use the standard solution if I can be sure the semantics will be maintained (i.e. I won't get any off-by-one-day errors). I first tried:

```
date.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDate()
```

but this did give an instance where the `Date` and `LocalDate` where off by 1 day.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: "Could I get different LocalDates depending on which system the code is executed?" Yes, but your `Calendar` code would do that too.

Comment: If you were using`Calendar.getInstance()` (which takes the default time zone and locale), there should not be **more** risk when using `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` ?

Comment: I think you might have to adjust your expectations. A `Date` represents a instant in time (n milliseconds since the epoch). You are trying to set the hour, minute, second components of that all to 0. But "hour and minute components" don't make sense in the context of an "instant in time". They _would_ make sense if you add a zone to it. `Calendar`, being badly designed, hides these details from you, and silently uses the system timezone. java.time on the other hand, asks you to provide a timezone, making you realise that this is _intrinsically_ timezone-dependent.

Comment: So judging from the comments by both @Sweeper and @TacheDeChoco can I assume that using `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` will always produce the same result as the previous code with `Calendar.getInstance()` since that is using `TimeZone.getDefault()` and `Locale.getDefault(Category)` under the hood?

Comment: @contiver I wouldn't say they are the same result. The `Calendar` code produces a `Date`, which is conceptually an _instant_ in time, whereas your java.time code produces a `LocalDate`, which is conceptually a year-month-day tuple. These are two very different concepts. They are the same only in the sense that the `Date`, when observed in the system timezone, will have the same year, month, day as the `LocalDate` produced by your java.time code.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, that's what I meant, sorry for the lousy/imprecise wording. What I care about is that both represent the same year, month and day when observed under the same system timezone. Thanks!